# Restructuring repeating columns into rows VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a wide data set composed of identifiers and then a series of 20 groups of repeating columns, with the same 8 columns in each group. I would like restructure these data into rows such that the identifiers each repeat and each series of 8 represents a unique row.

[What I currently have and what I'm trying to accomplish:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TwgI.png)

I have code that gets me most of the way there, it works if I just run it on the identifiers and the first two columns. It won't go through columns 3-8 of each group. Here is the code that successfully runs on the first two columns of each group.

```
Sub StackData()
    Dim Key, Dic As Object, cl As Range, Data As Range, i&, n&
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    i = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    n = 1
    Set Data = Range("F2:F" & i & "," & "N2:N" & i & "," & "V2:V" & i & "," & "AD2:AD" & i & "," & "AL2:AL" & i & "," & "AT2:AT" & i & "," & "BB2:BB" & i & "," & "BJ2:BJ" & i & "," & "BR2:BR" & i & "," & "BZ2:BZ" & i & "," & "CH2:CH" & i & "," & "CP2:CP" & i & "," & "CX2:CX" & i & "," & "DF2:DF" & i & "," & "DN2:DN" & i & "," & "DV2:DV" & i & "," & "ED2:ED" & i & "," & "EL2:EL" & i & "," & "ET2:ET" & i & "," & "FB2:FB" & i)
    Dic.Add "|Name", "Var1|Var2|Var3|Var4|Var5|Var6|Var7|Var8"
    For Each cl In Data
        If Cells(cl.Row, "A") <> "" Then
            Dic.Add n & "|" & Cells(cl.Row, "A"), cl.Text & "|" & cl.Offset(, 1).Text
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next cl
    n = 1
    For Each Key In Dic
        Worksheets("Worksheet").Cells(n, "A") = Split(Key, "|")(1)
        Worksheets("Worksheet").Cells(n, "B") = Split(Dic(Key), "|")(0)
        Worksheets("Worksheet").Cells(n, "C") = Split(Dic(Key), "|")(1)
        n = n + 1
    Next Key
End Sub
```

When I add to the "For each Key in Dic" I get an error. Any input as to what I am doing wrong? Also open to different ways to approach this that might be cleaner than this kludgey approach.

Comment: My actual dataset has 163 columns: 3 identifier columns, plus 20 groups of 8 columns. These 20 groups are in the same order so the first variable is the same in each group, second is the same, third and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with Power Query, available in Excel 2010+

In the code below I did it using your provided example.
You'll need to make a few changes to adapt it to your actual data.

eg:

- In the code, I selected the first **two** columns and Unpivoted other columns; in your actual data you'll have to select the first **three**
- For the Integer/Division column, I divided by **three**; you'll probably need to divide by **eight**
- In the code, I added **three** custom columns (one for each of the identifier columns, and one for the remaining.  You'll need to add **four** custom columns

In any event:

**MCode**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Name", "ID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Inserted Integer-Division" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Integer-Division", each Number.IntegerDivide([Index], 3), Int64.Type),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Integer-Division",{"Attribute", "Index"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Integer-Division"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Name=text, ID=number, Value=text, #"Integer-Division"=number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Name", each List.First(Table.Column([Grouped],"Name"))),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "ID", each List.First(Table.Column([Grouped],"ID"))),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom", each Table.Column([Grouped],"Value")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom2", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ";"), type text}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Custom.1", "Custom.2", "Custom.3"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Custom.1", type text}, {"Custom.2", type text}, {"Custom.3", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Integer-Division", "Grouped"}),

    //Rename last columns
        origColNames =List.Buffer(List.Range(Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Columns1"),2)),
        newNameNum =  List.Generate(() => 1 , each _ <=List.Count(origColNames), each _ + 1),

    //There has to be a better way to convert the numbers to strings
        #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(newNameNum, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
        #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", type text}}),

        newNames = Table.Column(#"Changed Type1","Column1"),
        renameCols = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns1",List.Zip({origColNames,newNames}))

in 
    renameCols
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Stack Data

- Copy the code into a standard module (e.g. `Module1`).
- Carefully adjust the values under `Source`, `Target` and `Workbook`.
- The code is written for `Thisworkbook`, the workbook containing this code.

**The Code**

```
Sub stackData()
    ' Error Handler
    Const Proc As String = "stackData"
    On Error GoTo cleanError

    ' Source
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"      ' Worksheet Name
    Const srcFirst As String = "A2"         ' First Cell Address
    Const LRCol As Long = 1                 ' Last Row Column Number
    Const IdentCols As Long = 3             ' Number of Identifier Columns
    Const GroupCols As Long = 8             ' Number of Group Columns
    Const GroupsCount As Long = 20          ' Number of Groups
    ' Target
    Const tgtName As String = "Sheet2"      ' Worksheet Name
    Const tgtFirst As String = "A2"         ' First Cell Address
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    ' Write values of Source Range to Source Array.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(srcName)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Columns(LRCol).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If rng.row < ws.Range(srcFirst).row Then Exit Sub
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = rng.row
    Set rng = Nothing
    Dim LastCol As Long: LastCol = IdentCols + GroupCols * GroupsCount
    Dim Source As Variant
    Source = ws.Range(ws.Range(srcFirst), ws.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    Set ws = Nothing
    Dim ubS As Long: ubS = UBound(Source)

    ' Write values of Source Array to Target Array.
    Dim Target As Variant
    ReDim Target(1 To ubS * GroupsCount, 1 To IdentCols + GroupCols)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, m As Long
    GoSub writeIdentifiers
    GoSub writeGroups

    ' Write values of Target Array to Target Range.
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(tgtName)
    ws.Range(tgtFirst).Resize(UBound(Target), UBound(Target, 2)).Value = Target

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data stacked.", vbInformation, "Success"

    Exit Sub

' Subroutines
writeIdentifiers:
    m = 1
    For i = 1 To ubS
        For j = 1 To GroupsCount
            For k = 1 To IdentCols
                Target(m, k) = Source(i, k)
            Next k
            m = m + 1
        Next j
    Next i
    Return

writeGroups:
    m = 1
    For i = 1 To ubS
        For j = 1 To GroupsCount
            For k = 1 To GroupCols
                Target(m, k + IdentCols) = _
                  Source(i, k + IdentCols + (j - 1) * GroupCols)
            Next k
            m = m + 1
        Next j
    Next i
    Return

' Error Handler
cleanError:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred in '" & Proc & "'." & vbCr _
         & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbCr & Err.Description _
           , vbCritical, Proc & " Error"
End Sub
```